# Stripe does not bind de event with {$event}

Tags: java, frameworks, stripes

I'm new to stripes, so I'm sorry if it is a easy question, right now I have this class:

```
 ....
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.DefaultHandler;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.DontValidate;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.ForwardResolution;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.HandlesEvent;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.RedirectResolution;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.Resolution;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.UrlBinding;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring.SpringBean;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.validation.ValidationMethod;
 import net.sourceforge.stripes.validation.ValidationState;

@UrlBinding("/role/{$event}")
public class RoleActionBean extends BaseActionBean {

    @DefaultHandler @DontValidate
    @HandlesEvent("add")
    public Resolution listrole() {
        ...
        return new ForwardResolution("/jsp/role/list.jsp");
    }

    @HandlesEvent("add") @DontValidate
    public Resolution addrole() {
        ...
        return new ForwardResolution("/jsp/role/add.jsp");
    }

    @HandlesEvent("save")
    public Resolution saverole() 
    {
        ...
    }

    @HandlesEvent("view") @DontValidate
    public Resolution viewrole() {
        ...
    }

    @HandlesEvent("edit") @DontValidate
    public Resolution editrole() {
        ...
    }

    @HandlesEvent("update")
    public Resolution updaterole() {
        ...
    }

    @HandlesEvent("delete")
    public Resolution deleterole() {
        ...
    }



    @ValidationMethod(on={"save", "update"}, when=ValidationState.ALWAYS)
    public void validarDatosrole(){
        ... 
    }


    @ValidationMethod(on={"save", "update"}, when=ValidationState.ALWAYS)
    public void validarDatosrole2(){
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

But when I try to, access the ActionBean to the url:

/role/add

Or any other of the events, I get the 404, I'm trying to get more clean URL so it will be more easy to restrict the users which action can use with spring security, before I have it working with:

```
@UrlBinding("/role.html")
```

and going to the URL:

role.html?add

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you have two handler methods for the `add` event. This causes stripes to fail to startup with the following exception (and then respond to all requests with a 404 because the servlet failed to start up)

```
2016-05-27 08:53:22,850 FATAL {main} [] net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter Could not instantiate specified Configuration. Class name specified was [net.sourceforge.stripes.config.RuntimeConfiguration].
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Problem instantiating default configuration objects.
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.config.DefaultConfiguration.init(DefaultConfiguration.java:210)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.config.RuntimeConfiguration.init(RuntimeConfiguration.java:276)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.createConfiguration(StripesFilter.java:137)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.init(StripesFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4076)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Could not instantiate configured ActionResolver of type [UIActionResolver]. Please check the configuration parameters specified in your web.xml.
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.config.RuntimeConfiguration.initializeComponent(RuntimeConfiguration.java:257)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.config.RuntimeConfiguration.initActionResolver(RuntimeConfiguration.java:119)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.config.DefaultConfiguration.init(DefaultConfiguration.java:102)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: The ActionBean class example.site.actions.help.RecordsAction declares multiple event handlers for event 'add'
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.processMethods(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:233)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.addActionBean(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:152)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.init(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:119)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.NameBasedActionResolver.init(NameBasedActionResolver.java:125)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.config.RuntimeConfiguration.initializeComponent(RuntimeConfiguration.java:253)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

[dhensche](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37485344/62462) is correct that you have too many add handlers in the code you posted.

If we assume that's just a copying error and your ActionBean was usable prior to your UrlBinding change, I think you may want to look at your servlet mapping configuration.

Since your link will no longer contain ".action", web requests may not know how to reach the StripesDispatcher, and that's why you're getting a 404 response.

This blog post has a detailed example of what you're trying to do: [Clean and usable URLs in Stripes](https://110j.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/clean-and-usable-urls-in-stripes/)

Also, you might want to consider naming your resolution methods to match the events they handle, and ditching the HandlesEvent annotations. Then it won't be possible to accidentally define duplicate handlers.